# Visual Studio 2013 New Project .csproj not supported

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I try to create a new Windows Forms project, I get the " ....csproj cannot be opened because its project type (.csproj) is not supported by this version of the application" error. The .csproj file it is referring to is in *AppData\Local\temp\randomname\Applicationname.csproj* but that file does not actually get created.

I know that when this error crops up with opening projects created in previous versions, it's usually a missing library that is used by that particular project but for the life of me, I cannot figure out what library I could be missing here as it is a new project.

I have VS 2013 Ultimate installed with all components.

Running on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

First confirm it is not a add-on or a problem with Visual Studio itself. 
Try and start Visual Studio from the command line with ***devenv.exe /resetskippkgs*** and also try disable any IDE extensions temporarily to see if one of them might be stepping on something. Do these two things first to see if the problem lies with VS IDE. Of course try creating a project after you have done these two things and see if you get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out what the actual problem was but I've installed Update 5 which was only released less than two weeks ago and it's working fine now.